# Error : "No match for 'operator <<' (operand types are std::istream)

Tags: c++, c++11

This is my first StackOverflow and happy to join.
I'm currently studying C++ with Stroustrup's "Programming and Practice using C++" and for now we are using a library he created (#include "std_lib_facilities.h")

I finished an exercise and got this error
"No match for 'operator <<' (operand types are std::istream)"

The program I wrote may not be perfect yet but I can't even compile it at this point. I've read in other posts something about "overload operator" but I don't understand what it means and specifically why in my other files this does not happen even with the same library loaded.

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    double val1 = 0;
    double val2 = 0;

    cin << val1 << val2 << endl;

    if (val1>val2)
        cout << val1 << " is larger than " << val2 <<endl;
    else
        cout << val1 << " is smaller than " << val2 <<endl;
```

}

Comment: `cin >> val1 >> val2;` should do what you want.

Comment: cin is an input stream as a result the insertion(write) operator(**operator <<**) is not defined for it. As has been mention in other comment you use cin for input with the extraction(get) operator(**operator>>**)

Comment: This is why I say "the compiler is your friend." It tells you "there is no << for istream."  That's really useful information. You look more closely at the book and realize it should be >>. (I remember them by thinking of info going from cin to the variable, or from the variable to cout, with arrows.

Answer (score 2):

You should use **>> operator** for input in c++. This is called extraction operator that is used to get value from keyboard or others like files. Syntax is :

```
int variableName;

cout << "Enter number";
cin >>  variableName;
```

**<< operator**  is  insertion operater used for written data on screen or files.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`operator>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) with [`std::cin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin), which is a [`std::istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) and doesn't support `operator<<`.

```
std::cin >> val1 >> val2;
```

Comment: did you mean **as std::ostream**?

Comment: @bkVnet `std::cin`? No it's `std::istream`.

Comment: I mean when you said "which doesn't support operator<< as a std::istream". Does **std::istream** support **operator<<**?

Comment: Thanks all! That was great

Comment: @bkVnet I got what you mean. I've updated the answer to avoid misunderstanding.